# Name of qgis2web export folders?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, export, qgis2web

When I export to webmap with qgis2web, it creates a new folder with a default name (for example "qgis2web_2018_11_14-17_24_47_123987") that relays on the precise time when it is created, but I need to know the exact name of the folder where the webmap it's going to be before being exported.

Is there a way to change these default folder names?

Comment: Can'n you select and edit the Export folder like in this tutorial https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html?

Comment: No, if I choose an export folder it just creates another folder type "qgis2web_2018_11_14-17_24_47_123987" inside that export folder I chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not currently possible. The unique folder name is required to ensure that users don't overwrite previous exports. There is therefore no way to know the folder name before export.

If the parent folder (set as described in the comment by @user30184 above) only contains qgis2web exports, you can reliably predict that your last export is the last subfolder, sorted by name. I don't know if that might help you.